# What is a "protected" post status?

Tags: post-status, core

I noticed in the [`register_post_status`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_post_status/) function in core that there is an arg for 'protected'.

The following post statuses: 'future', 'draft', and 'pending'  all have this set to **true**.

I'm not talking about a protected 'post' but the 'protected' argument used when registering a custom `post_status`.

What does this 'protected' status do? And why would I make a custom post status protected?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`register_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_status/) is used for creating a custom post status.  The protected argument, if true, specifies that a user must be logged in and have edit permissions on the post to view (preview) it.

For example, you said that the "draft" post status has `protected` set to true.  This means that you can only view (preview) the draft post if you have permission to edit the post.  Once the post is published, the `protected` parameter is turned off and anyone can view it.

If you are creating your own custom status, you might want it to be protected.  For example, you could have a post status called "on_hold", and when you set a post to that status, it would no longer be visible to the public, but still visible to the administrators of your site.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC it's if a post is password protected.

Comment: Correct. You can set a password on a page, but still have it accessible without someone logging in - they just need to know the password.

Comment: I think it's unrelated to password protected posts. The 'protected' argument is used in `register_post_status`. It's related to a post status, not an individual post. If that were true, then I would think that all 'future', 'draft' and 'pending' posts would all be password protected.